# How to specify w2ui panel size in em instead of px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, w2ui

w2ui layout examples use pixels for panel size: http://w2ui.com/web/demos/#!layout/layout-1

However, I want to specify panel size in em. Is it possible?

Comment: Several people spent time to downvote my question, yet none of them cared to answer. So much for help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:**

No. Only `px` (default if no unit is specified) and `%` are supported.

**Long answer:**

While it is possible to force a specific height/width for individual panels by using the panel's `style` property (e.g. `style: "height: 15em !important;"`), I would not suggest to use it, because the height/width of other panels is still calculated by the original `size` property.

If you want to do it that way, be prepared that you will have to specify all height/width values yourself for all panels and resizing will not work - at which point there's probably no longer a benefit of using the w2layout over designing something with flex boxes yourself.